# xcode run on load ibaction

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

I'm trying to have the yespic show on load.  I'm new to xcode.  lots of ASP classic experience.  Currently when this viewcontroller appears there is no image.  then if you press the yespic, an image will show.  I want it to show the image on load.  I'm lost now four days.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
-(IBAction) yespic;
{
    UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"eggplant.png"];
    [imageView setImage:img];
    // I can use this to show if they have paid for something.
}
-(IBAction) nopic;
{
    UIImage *img =nil;
    [imageView setImage:img];

}
```

Comment: This comment in the code may give you a clue: `// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.`

Comment: That does not help, thanks anyhow.

Comment: Move the code that you have in "yes pic" into viewDidLoad, an IBAction is a "button listener" in iOS so the reason that nothing happens unless you press the button is because you haven't done anything until the button is pressed. viewDidLoad is where your typically set images like you are here if it is supposed to happen before it becomes visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:@"eggplant.png"];
        [imageView setImage:img];
    }

- (IBAction) yespic
{

}

- (IBAction) nopic
{
    UIImage *img =nil;
    [imageView setImage:img];

}
```

Comment: This worked, and I understand some more.  Thank you.